# Python setter TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, oop, object, getter-setter

I am trying to create a setter for my private self.__food variable. Basically i want the childclass Tiger to change the private variable which has a condition to limit the value over 100. However i receive an error : TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Where am I wrong and how can i fix this? Thanks

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self,foodamount=10, location = 'Australia'):
        self.__food = foodamount
        self.location = location

    @property
    def foodamt(self):
        return self.__food

    @foodamt.setter
    def foodsetter(self, foodamount):
        if self.__food >100:
            self.__food = 100
        else: self.__food = foodamount


class Tiger(Animal):
    def __init__(self,colour = 'orange'):
        super().__init__(location ='programming and gaming')
        self.colour = colour


an = Tiger()
an.colour='red'
print(an.colour)
ansetfood = an.foodsetter(1000)
print(ansetfood)
```

Comment: This is not how you define a setter. Use the same method name (property name) as the getter\propery (foomat, not foodsetter). See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see a couple problems.

- When using a property, you do not manually call the setter's name like `an.foodsetter(1000)`. You use attribute assignment syntax, like `an.foodamt = 1000`. This is the entire point of properties: to have transparent attribute-like syntax while still having function-like behavior.
- You should be comparing `foodamount` to 100, not `self.__food`.
- a property's getter and setter should have the same name.

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self,foodamount=10, location = 'Australia'):
        self.__food = foodamount
        self.location = location

    @property
    def foodamt(self):
        return self.__food

    @foodamt.setter
    def foodamt(self, foodamount):
        if foodamount >100:
            self.__food = 100
        else: self.__food = foodamount


class Tiger(Animal):
    def __init__(self,colour = 'orange'):
        super().__init__(location ='programming and gaming')
        self.colour = colour


an = Animal()
an.colour='red'
print(an.colour)
an.foodamt = 1000
print(an.foodamt)
```

Result:

```
red
100
```

Comment: You don't need to pass `self` to `super`

Comment: Strange, `super` seemed to require `self` while I was composing the answer, but now it doesn't. Alright, edited. Thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Could you also recommend any Websites/Tutorials where i  can better understand where OOP is used. It's still kind of abstract to me